# How do i use this javascript variable properly?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to expand on some code written by someone else, but I am having trouble using one of the javascript variables. If I set it in the title of a div or something similar like so:

```
$("#test12").attr("title" , ccode);
```

then it works fine and the title of the div is 'CA', which it should be. But if I try to put it into the text area of the div, then it tries to run a function or something but I can't see where it's doing it.

Is there a way I can convert it to simple text and stop it from running any functions?

Thanks for any help

Edit:

This is all of the code I can see at the moment:

```
<script>

//<!--
function loadForeignOffices(ccode){

    //load window with details...
    $('#iframe_3').attr("src", "<?php echo $html->url("/", true); ?>erc/maps/contacts/"+ccode);
    $("#test12").attr("title" , ccode);



}
//-->
</script>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is use the ccode variable because I want to display CA on the screen, but when I try to do that it seems to run some other function and fails, and doesnt show CA.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code, its hard to understand what your asking

Comment: +1 to @Chris.  Let's see some more code.

Comment: What Chris said, no one can help you unless we see that other bit of code..

Comment: Just do: `$("#textarea").html(ccode);`.  What's the problem here?  We need more info.

Comment: Note that the code you posted is the server side code (it has a php echo statement), what does the source of this look like on the client side (after the php has been processed?) Also: any errors in the error console?

Comment: Thanks Rocket, I thought .load did pretty much the same thing...I'll make sure to read up more on these :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to brush up on your jQuery dot-operators:

`.load()` is an ajax call that will load the contents of `()` into the selected element. In one of your comments you mention you are trying to do this `$("#test12").load(ccode);` which is inherently silly, if ccode is the string "CA"

`.attr()` will change the attributes of the selected element. If you are trying to display "CA", `$("#test12").attr("title" , ccode);` this will clearly not accomplish that -- As "CA" is added to the title attribute. As in `<div id="test12" title="CA"></div>`

Perhaps what you are looking for is `.html()` which inserts the string into the selected element. Or even `.innerText()`

Why don't you spend some time reading [the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). A little bit goes a long way!

Comment: Yep this is something I need to read up on, the .html was what I meant to do...thanks! I thought .load() did pretty much the same thing but obviously I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind your PHP code is executing first on the server, **then** your javascript.

Here's a **JS Fiddle** as a start: http://jsfiddle.net/QsFJ4/3/

Comment: Hi pixelbobby, I'm finding it hard to explain what I mean. If i use this code: $("#test12").load(ccode); instead of the attr("title..." one then it doesn't display the same output

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not sure anyone is going to understand that.  What exatly are you trying to accomplish?  Why are we comparing a `src` attribute to a `title` attribute?